# Business Rule Violations and Exceptions

Tags: c#, oop, coding-style, business-logic

Can someone help me with a link to an article, or a link to a SO post that contains a link, on why its not a good idea to model business rule violations with exceptions. I'd also be happy with a reference to a book and page, if the book was available on Safari, and an extract from the book would be double plus good!

**I've** seen plenty of good reasons in questions and answers I've looked at on SO, but others need something a little more authoritative (something in the Fowler/Evans league would be nice).

Thanks

Comment: Does it need to be in a book to be authoritative! Who says so?

Comment: A web article is fine, but it would need to be from someone/somewhere that is authoritative. A link to an article on codeproject / reddit / random SO answer wouldnt be enough. (For me, a SO answer with +20/author rep 10k would be enough, but its not enough for others...)

Comment: would people care to comment on the close votes? right now I have the development equivalent of `throw new Exception()` level of information.

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not read these completely, I think these links (one of them is from Google Books) should be useful to you as they are mostly related to modelling business rules authored by Ronald G. Ross ([brcommunity.com](http://brcommunity.com)):

http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Uyv9hMOt6BsC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=business+rule+violations&source=bl&ots=8fb5Vqgi3K&sig=DNUkrv4wNZTX755rVk2gv0upzUs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QYsFT7ezEOf10gH68tmLAg&ved=0CFsQ6AEwCDgK#v=onepage&q=business%20rule%20violations&f=false

http://www.brcommunity.com/b335.php

Comment: Thanks for the links, that Principles of the Business Rule Approach book looks like a good read. I dont see anything (after a quick read), that states modeling rule violations with exceptions (the programming language construct) is bad practice. Did you see this anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find an authoritive answer in any book. Some people will claim throwing exceptions is very expensive in C#. Others (like me) will tell you to not worry about it, unless you're building a semi-realtime system. I've been throwing RuleViolationExceptions in all my major enterprise-class systems because I've seen that this works a lot better than having every method in you domain return some kind of error code. In fact, I think it's a best practice, so I've included this in my [Silverlight Cookbook](http://silverlightcookbook.codeplex.com/) project.

Comment: hmm. Does that not lead us down the road of everything that is not 'the happy case' is now an exception? Personally I feel this model is wrong, as you're now using an exception as a transport for BL info, and you also are left with an issue of, what is 'the happy case'.

Comment: You might, but I use something like http://silverlightcookbook.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/88277#2123097 to collect all my business rule violations and throw them just around the service layer.